# How do i protect backend REST APIs on App Engine and GKE from abuse?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

What are the best practices for protecting public REST APIs on Google App Engine and/or Kubernetes Engine from abuse?  I intend to develop APIs that will be invoked from an Android App or a React Front End application.

I dont mind authorization via oauth2/google etc.  Wondering how others are doing this...  I would ideally like for some part of my website to be browse-able for non-registered/anonymous users and would not like to impose google sign-on or registration at the very first step.

I am starting with something that is more or less a small hobby project for now.  Would not want to incur huge costs because of abuse of public APIs.

I did a fair bit of research but could not conclude on a way forward.  Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit access, abuse, rate limits, quotas, (...) software proxy is the solution. [Apigee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/) is expensive and very powerful.

An open source solution exists: [ESP Endpoint](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp). You can deploy it on AppEngine or on Cloud Run and thanks to configuration you can protect some part of your application, make redirection/rewrite, set limit and quotas,... I think this is for you.

Comment: Will definitely look into it. Thanks!